# Combine multiple graphics2d composites?

Tags: java, transparency, bufferedimage, graphics2d

How can i combine 2 composites in to one? Let me explain:

```
BufferedImage copy = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = copy.createGraphics();
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
```

Now we have a transparent image.

```
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
```

Now we have an exact copy of the "img" including the transparent areas.

```
g2d.setComposite(BlendComposite.getInstance(BlendingMode.MULTIPLY));
g2d.setColor(overlayColor);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
```

(BlendComposite from http://www.curious-creature.com/2006/09/20/new-blendings-modes-for-java2d/) 
At this point the the multiply composite has given the image a nice color (overlayColor).

But the transparent areas now have the same color as overlayColor.

How can i prevent the transparent area's from getting the overlayColor?

Comment: I suspect that you can't. But you can work around it by "restoring" the alpha from the original, using an step I guess.

Comment: @haraldK , the big question is how? ;-) If i knew or had found a way to do this i would be very happy.

Comment: Paint the original (`img`) over the `copy` (using the existing `g2d`) with `DstIn` `AlphaComposite`?

Comment: @haraldK that works! Not sure why, but I'm going to read a bit more about the AlphaComposite. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For anyone with the same problem: If pixels in the source and the destination overlap, the alpha from the source is applied to the destination pixels in the overlapping area. If the alpha = 1.0, the pixels in the overlapping area are unchanged; if the alpha is 0.0, pixels in the overlapping area are cleared. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html

Comment: Feel free/please to post your solution as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@haraldK point me to a nice working solution:

> Paint the original (img) over the copy (using the existing g2d) with
>   DstIn AlphaComposite?

I gave it a try just after the multiply step:

```
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstIn);
g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0,    null);
```

And it now works, i have my transparency back!

For anyone with the same problem:

AlphaComposite.DstIn:

If pixels in the source and the destination overlap, the alpha from the source is applied to the destination pixels in the overlapping area. If the alpha = 1.0, the pixels in the overlapping area are unchanged; if the alpha is 0.0, pixels in the overlapping area are cleared.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html